# Should I change ground level slope to resolve water draining to finished portion of basement?

Tags: drainage, basement-refinishing

TL;DR: my sump pump area under the Bilco door sometimes drains water into finished portion of basement.  Should  I change the slope so that the water cannot run from the Bilco door sump area?

The Bilco door area tends to leak some rain water, and I get residual rain water going under the door threshold and into the basement, from the walls (not from sump pump overflow).  I want to stop this.  The slope of the Bilco area is downwards towards the door,   Hence the issues.  I was considering pouring some concrete to make this area flat or (even better) drain downwards towards the pump.

Is this a bad idea?  The can I can see if that in an emergency water leaking into the basement from other sources would not be able to get to the sump.  But I have only seen the other way around (water from Bilco sumo area getting into rest of basement.).

[image]

Comment: Are there drain lines going into the pit? Does one of them appear to travel below the area with the drainage problem?

Comment: That's an odd place for the pit.  Difficult to inspect and service, and obviously you have wires and pipes snaking though your staircase.  Aside from the water that leaks through the door from above, how else does water enter the pit?  And why does the pump's discharge pipe initially travel *towards* your house?  Anyway, yes, directing water that drips through the doors into the pit is a good idea but a broader understanding would help.

Comment: Also, if you have water leaking into the area, stairs supported on unfinished bits of wood nailed to the stringer aren't going to last long.  You're supported by rusty nails.

Comment: No drain lines going Into the sump pit, water is only supposed to enter the pit from the ground up.  Groundwater. The discharge pipe goes through a concrete structure the bilco is built on, and underground to a marsh where it drains.

Comment: No drain lines suggests that there's a nice layer of permeable gravel intended to allow water to drain from far and wide. If the pit goes well below the bottom of slab elevation, then you can just punch a hole in the floor for drainage anywhere, no?

Comment: Interesting idea.. the sump pit does go down probably 24” or more.  I suppose I could add additional holes but it’s not ideal for me because of lack of a jackhammer, having to remove door frame, and cosmetically having more holes in the floor.

Comment: You might just have pea gravel around the perimeter, where I would drill there out of caution. My hack instinct is to use a rotary hammer to punch a cluster of 3/4" holes. In a pinch I've drilled holes and connected them to push a 6" duct through a foundation into an addition. Some mortar plus a drain, I suspect, could phony up a nice looking drain that way.